# Polylines rotation through the model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am searching to add rotation to polylines through the model builder.
Is anybody familiar with such option?

Answer (score 2):

There are no base tools you can incorporate directly into model builder.  Instead, you will have to produce a [script tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000006000000) and incorporate it into your model.  You are in luck though because folks have already done this on the ESRI forum: [Rotate Features Using Arcpy](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/53828-Rotate-Features-using-ArcPy).